# Win 10 Bat to Disable/Enable User accounts

Tags: windows, batch-file

I Need to Make a bat script that can be ran to disable certain user accounts.
ex. Tim Jim Lin (all Local Accounts)

and a way to re enable these accounts with the same bat or second one 
(reason is to not have these accounts show up at the login screen.)

I can currently do this manually by Computer management.
Local Users (account) Propertys and checking Disable Account.
I need to make it more User Friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
net user %username% /ACTIVE:NO /domain
```

Comment: Thank you that was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a registry key to hide (local) accounts from the login screen,
so there is no need to disable the accounts and you can still remotely login RDP/SSH etc.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
    Tim    REG_DWORD    0x0
    Jim    REG_DWORD    0x0
    Lin    REG_DWORD    0x0
```

To unhide set them to 0x1 or remove them.

A batch to set these

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\18\SO_52880534.cmd

Set "Key=HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList"
Set "Typ=Reg_DWORD"
SET "Dat=0x0"

For %%U in (Tim Jim Lin) Do (
    Reg Add "%Key%" /V %%U /T %Typ% /D %Dat% /F
)
Reg Query "%Key%"
```

To get a list of local users account process output of `net user` :

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\18\SO_52880534_2.cmd
@Echo off
for /F "skip=4 delims=" %%A in (
    'net user^| find /V "."'
) Do For %%B in (%%A) Do Echo %%B
```

Or invoke powershell as a tool

```
 powershell -nop -c "(Get-LocalUser).Name"
```